# Combining multiple commands to render out different formats, while also resyncing the original file, and not have to render that one out first

Tags: ffmpeg, video, encoding

After recording a live show, there are several tasks I need to do before I can render out the video file to different formats. I need to trim the file, and then resync the audio as well. After this I render the video file out to WAV, MP3 and MP4. I created a script like the one below (omitting the command for mp3, as this is just an example).

I'm obviously not very well versed in ffmpeg commands. The way this script works I first create a trimmed version, and then a second version that has the audio synced, before it finally does the encoding to other formats. Since I often have to do several massive files, I run into serious disk space problems with all the intermediary files being rendered out first.

Is there a way to combine the trim and resync command into one, so I can render out a trimmed and resynced master file?

```
ffmpeg -i ORIGINAL_TRIM.mxf -itsoffset 0.200 -i ORIGINAL_TRIM.mxf -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy ORIGINAL_RESYNC.mxf

ffmpeg -i ORIGINAL_RESYNC.mxf -vn ORIGINAL.wav

ffmpeg -i ORIGINAL_RESYNC.mxf -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -c:a aac ORIGINAL.mp4
```

Pause

Answer (score 1):

As shown below,

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -to 00:45:00 -i ORIGINAL.mxf
       -ss 00:01:00 -to 00:45:00 -itsoffset 0.200 -i ORIGINAL.mxf
       -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -c:a aac ORIGINAL.mp4
       -map 1:a -vn ORIGINAL.wav
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much! One other thing though. How do I also keep a master recording (the mxf in this case) that is resynced? In this answer the original is encoded to different formats like I asked, and to see the syntax is great, but I also need a version that is not re-encoded, just with the audio corrected.

Comment: Actually. I have been trying to use the code a few times but the result is error notifications. I can't post it here as it has too many characters to post.